# C the programming language "Character Counter" example won't run

Tags: c, xcode, sample

I'm completely new to C, and I am attempting to run this example code on xcode, but it says build failed. I got the code exact like it is in the book, but it still won't run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count characters in input; 2nd version */
int main()
{
    double nc;
    for (nc =0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc) {
        ;
    }
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

Sorry if it's a noob question. All help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't have a return statement in main.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Paste the entire build output from xcode into this question. The code itself is valid, it may be a configuration issue.

Comment: @Claris this is the output.                                                adddsadsd
33334343434243
Program ended with exit code: 9

Comment: Xcode 5.1 builds and runs this just fine. `main()` (uniquely) does not require an explicit `return` statement, it'll implicitly `return 0` for you if you leave it out. Typing input into the debug window and hitting `CTRL-D` to end produces the desired output for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question code lacks a 'return {int value}' statement.  I added this missing line, and ended up with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count characters in input; 2nd version */
int main()
{
   double nc;
   for (nc =0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc) {
       ;
      }
   printf("%.0f\n", nc);

   return(0);
}
```

The above compiled without errors or warnings using:

```
gcc -Wall -o test test.c
```

To run it requires that input to the program comes from a file.
I made a file named 'junk.txt' with the following content (not including the braces):

```
[ adddsadsd 33334343434243]
```

Then I executed the program using the following command:

```
./test < junk.txt
```

which generated the output:

```
25
```

Comment: As you're a learner, `Kenshin`, be aware that `return` isn't actually a function and can equally be written `return 0;`. Adding the brackets is a style preference. So you'll see it written without brackets elsewhere but don't worry about it: it means the same thing.

Comment: Note that in C99 and C11, for compatibility with C++98 and later, you are permitted (but not AFAIAC recommended) to omit the `return` from the end of `main` and the result is equivalent to `return 0;`.  Personally, I put the `return 0;` in the code.  This permission was not present in C89, and by default GCC compiles for C89 (or GNU89).